# how to set 3 range zero in double in android java

Tags: java, android, double

When I enter the number 0.0007575 on the double, the result will be "7.575E-4", but I want result 0.0007575

thanks

Comment: It's the same value but is displayed (somewhere) in exponential notation format.  Please update with some code to show where the value is not displayed as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom [`DecimalFormat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat) to format the double value:

```
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#0.000"); // leading zero and 3 fraction digits
String result = fmt.format(11.123456789);
System.out.println(result); // 11.123
```